# How to create a Trusted CA Signed certificate for Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, x509certificate

All the documentation for Service Fabric mentions that for a production cluster you should use an X509 certificate from a trusted CA with the common name of the cluster address. The problem is I can't find any documentation on the process of obtaining the certificate. As far as I can tell for creating a certificate you need to prove you are who you say you are and to do so you either need to own the domain or expose some sort of file on the specified address.

The problem is that the url of the cluster is on a domain owned by Microsoft and my cluster is not exposed to the outside world as a website. Am I missing something? Do I have to create a web service and expose it in order to just create a certificate?

Comment: Certbot for letsencrypt service can run in standalone mode, exposing 80/443 ports to get certificates from letsencrypt. Take a look at its documentation. Perhaps that's what your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any a free solution like Letsencrypt, for this it's not required to own the domain (specifically; control the DNS records). They also provide the option to respond to a [HTTP based challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/), as proof of control.

> To kick off the process, the agent asks the Let’s Encrypt CA what it
>   needs to do in order to prove that it controls example.com. The Let’s
>   Encrypt CA will look at the domain name being requested and issue one
>   or more sets of challenges. These are different ways that the agent
>   can prove control of the domain. For example, the CA might give the
>   agent a choice of either: Provisioning a DNS record under example.com,
>   or Provisioning an HTTP resource under a well-known URI on
>   https://example.com/

An easy way to get started with Letsencrypt is by using [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/). 
This needs to run on the domain, so it can respond to the HTTP challenge, which results in the issuing of a certificate for your specific cluster endpoint.

Maybe this [sample project](https://github.com/fszlin/certes) helps.